# How can I refactor this code

Tags: haskell

I am trying to refactor the following (working) code (part of the excellent [NICTA Haskell course](https://github.com/NICTA/course)):

```
instance Extend ListZipper where
  f <<= z = 
    ListZipper (unfoldr ((<$>) (\z' -> (f z', z')) . toOptional . moveLeft) z)
               (f z)
               (unfoldr ((<$>) (\z' -> (f z', z')) . toOptional . moveRight) z)
```

to the following:

```
instance Extend ListZipper where
  f <<= z = ListZipper (go moveLeft) (f z) (go moveRight)
      where go f = unfoldr ((<$>) (\z' -> (f z', z')) . toOptional . f) z
```

but unfortunately I get the following compilation error:

```
src/Course/ListZipper.hs:669:25:
    Couldn't match type `b' with `MaybeListZipper a'
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            <<= :: (ListZipper a -> b) -> ListZipper a -> ListZipper b
          at src/Course/ListZipper.hs:669:3
    Expected type: List b
      Actual type: List (MaybeListZipper a)
    In the return type of a call of `go'
    In the first argument of `ListZipper', namely `(go moveLeft)'
    In the expression: ListZipper (go moveLeft) (f z) (go moveRight)
```

Have I missed something small or maybe something more fundamental ?
Is a refactoring like this possible (or even desirable) in idiomatic Haskell ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are shadowing the original `f` with a new `f`. Try renaming the second `f`, as in

```
instance Extend ListZipper where
  f <<= z = ListZipper (go moveLeft) (f z) (go moveRight)
      where go g = unfoldr ((<$>) (\z' -> (f z', z')) . toOptional . g) z
```

Answer (score 3):

You use `f` here, and it refers to the first operand of `<<=`.

```
(unfoldr ((<$>) (\z' -> (f z', z')) . toOptional . moveLeft) z)
```

When you use it here, it refers to the function passed to `go`.

```
where go f = unfoldr ((<$>) (\z' -> (f z', z')) . toOptional . f) z
```

Pick a different name!